# Most idiomatic way of replacing a list subsection in Lisp

Tags: list, lisp, common-lisp, replace

What is the best way of replacing a specific subsequence of a list?
Say I wanted to replace the subsequence `(m e)` with an `i`:

```
(sub-substitute 'i '(m e) '(y o u a n d m e))
⇒ (Y O U A N D I)
```

***Nota bene:** This is very similar to the function `substitute`:*

```
(substitute 'u 'i '(i are hungry))
⇒ (U ARE HUNGRY)
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I'm not sure if this is homework, and it's a legitimate practical question, so I'll give you a simple solution your teacher won't expect and will be curious about, if you have just been introduced to simple list processing. It works for sequences (vectors, lists, strings), and uses a few of CL's sequence functions:

```
(defun substitute-subsequence (new old sequence &key (test #'eql))
  (let ((position (search old sequence :test test)))
    (if position
        (concatenate (etypecase sequence
                       (string 'string)
                       (vector 'vector)
                       (list 'list))
                     (subseq sequence 0 position)
                     new
                     (subseq sequence (+ position (length old))))
        sequence)))
```

Then:

```
CL-USER> (substitute-subsequence '(i) '(m e) '(y o u a n d m e))
(Y O U A N D I)
CL-USER> (substitute-subsequence #(i) #(m e) #(y o u a n d m e))
#(Y O U A N D I)
CL-USER> (substitute-subsequence "I" "me" "you and me")
"you and I"
CL-USER> (substitute-subsequence "me" "I" "you and I")
"you and me"
```

If this was a homework question, you should think about ways to code a specific version only working with the list functions you have been introduced to. Also, note that concatenation and computing the length is not very efficient on lists, one should avoid it in tight loops. You could also try implementing a version that substitutes all occurrences.

EDIT: Shorter version, which substitutes all occurrences, but only works for lists:

```
(defun substitute-sublists (new old list)
  (do ((pos (search old list) (search old list :start2 pos)))
      ((not pos) list)
    (setq list (append (subseq list 0 pos) new (subseq list (+ pos (length old)))))))
```

Comment: It's not for homework, it was to implement Rule III from GEB's `MIU-system` (i.e. “If `III` occurs in one of the strings in your collection, you may make a new string with `U` in place of `III`”) — I had hoped for an elegant solution to this problem.

Comment: The functionality you want is not in the standard AFAIK, so there are two possibilities: Either you use a library which provides it, or you write it yourself. If you write it yourself, I don't see anything inelegant about my code. Now, if you want something shorter which works for all occurrences: I've updated the post. If elegant means built-in, I can't help.

Comment: I apologize, I didn't mean to disparage your code. Since Lisp has such a faculty for list manipulation I expected it to have some standard functionality that didn't require messing around with positional values. I'll upvote your answer but wait with accepting should someone think of a built-in function

Comment: @Baldur, no need to apologize -- I just wanted to point out that I don't know a "more elegant" way, and that the code I posted should be ok.